# ASP ListView SelectedIndexChanged/Changing Fires in Internet Explorer for All Records ONLY

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, listview

I have got an ASP `ListView`, bound programmatically to its `DataSource` at runtime.

Firefox and Chrome browsers have the issue where ONLY the first record of the ListView is causing the SelectedIndexChanged/Changing events to fire. All other selected records (2nd, 3rd, 4th record etc) are causing a Postback only, without the SelectedIndecChanged/Changing events being fired.

The strange thing, is that Internet Explorer fires the SelectedIndexChanged/Changing events on every record (not just the first record).

Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong?

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvUsersShoppingCart" runat="server" DataKeyField="ProductID" DataKeyNames="ProductID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lvUsersShoppingCart_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="top-buffer">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <asp:Image ID="imgProductThumbnail" class="img-responsive" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ThumbnailImageLocation")%>' />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <form class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <strong>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblProductName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName")%>' /></strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblProductShortDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductShortDescription")%>' />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            $<asp:Label ID="lblProductPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductPrice")%>' />
                            (AUD)
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group hidden">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <label for="lblProductQuantity" class="control-label">Quantity</label>
                            </div>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblProductQuantity" class="input-sm" runat="server" Text='<%# " x " + Eval("ProductQuantity").ToString%>'></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnEditQuantity" runat="server" Text="Change Qty" CssClass="btn btn-link" CommandName="Edit" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Remove" CssClass="btn btn-danger" CommandName="Select" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: I have no idea why the markup is not showing correctly!

Comment: post code in comment

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the `form` element in your `ItemTemplate`:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
...
</form>
```

You can get the correct behavior if you replace it by another type of container (typically a `div`):

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
...
</div>
```